# convert .sblive file to .iso

Tags: live-usb

I just created bootable LIVE image of current installed Ubuntu using systemback.
 the format of the file is `.sblive`. how do I convert it to `.iso`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your .sblive file is larger than 4 GB, the conversion to a .iso file is not possible.

This is a file system limitation.

You should find an .sblive image in the defined storage location ready to convert to .iso image.

If you've installed too many applications on the system, the size will reach beyond 4 GB, and you won't be able to convert it.

[image]

Comment: I asked how to convert .sblive to .iso

Comment: In Systemback, locate a .sblive image and press button -- Convert to ISO